# How to get local variable value from Invoke-command -Asjob?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I want to run [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("mail") on remote computers and write it.

```
Foreach($PCName in $PCNameArray) {
    $arrayJobs += Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -scriptblock { 
                param (
                    [String]$ip                )
                $IPs = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("mail")
                $ip = $ips[0]
    } -ComputerName $PCName -AsJob -ArgumentList $ip
}

Wait-Job $arrayJobs

$ResultArray=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

foreach ($job in $arrayJobs) {
    if ($job.State -eq 'Completed') {
        $ResultArray += Receive-Job $job
    } 
    Stop-Job $job
}

$ResultArray | Select PsComputerName,ip | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

How can get $ip value from inside Invoke-Command for all jobs?

Comment: Change `$ip = $ips[0]` to just `$ips[0]`, or `$ips |Select-Object -First 1`

Comment: I asked about something else, sorry if I confused you... I just want know IP of "mail" host inside of every job, and get this parameter to outside, to some $ResultArray jobs array, from where for example I want get:
for Job1 - $Resultarray.PSComputername=Host1, Resultarray.IP=192.168.100.1
for Job2 - $Resultarray.PSComputername=Host2, Resultarray.IP=192.168.100.3
for Job3 - $Resultarray.PSComputername=Host3, Resultarray.IP=192.168.100.1
something like this

Comment: Yup, I understood that. Did you try what I suggested? You'll need to change `Select PSComputerName,ip` to `Select PSComputerName,@{Name='ip';Expression='IPAddressToString'}` also :)

Comment: please check my answer, I post modifyed code, but it doesnt work too

Comment: Please describe what happens - does it give you the wrong data in the csv? Does it fail with an error message? If so, what's the error message? I can't see your screen :)

Comment: oh I'm sorry, it was because of blocking my AD user. I unblocked it, now it works fine! Yesm, it starts working after your changes, just my user was blocked last 5 minutes... Thank you! =) Can I post all my correct code as answer? (I'm not sure because I had  -1 for it, and delete it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, all you have to do is to *not* assign the desired value to a variable, and instead let PowerShell return it:

```
Foreach($PCName in $PCNameArray) {
    $arrayJobs += Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -scriptblock { 
                param (
                    [String]$ip                )
                $IPs = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("mail")
                $ips[0] # don't assign, just evaluate
    } -ComputerName $PCName -AsJob -ArgumentList $ip
}

Wait-Job $arrayJobs

$ResultArray=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

foreach ($job in $arrayJobs) {
    if ($job.State -eq 'Completed') {
        $ResultArray += Receive-Job $job
    } 
    Stop-Job $job
}

$ResultArray | Select PsComputerName,@{Name='IP';Expression='IPAddressToString'} | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
```

The `IPAddressToString` property on the resulting `[ipaddress]` objects will give you the string representation, eg. `10.0.0.1`